# Converting text string to end of month google sheets

Tags: string, date, google-sheets, text

I need to convert an imported string 30.03.2022 12:40:17 into end of the month date.

I tried

=LEFT(A2, LEN(A2) - 9)

got

30.03.2022

but when I tried to use EOMONTH on this I get a parse error.

Thanks a lot for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is same structure then use-

```
=EOMONTH(DATE(MID(A1,7,4),MID(A1,4,2),MID(A1,1,2)),0)
```

[image]